# how to filter my recyclerview with 2 items?

Tags: java, android, filter, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview and 2 list of cities (list of origin cities and destination cities) . i want to select a city from the first list and then select the destination city from the second list  and then recyclerview has been filtered and just shows the item with this origin and destination cities. the problem is : when i select origin city the recyclerview become empty and after selecting destination city it works. i want when i select first city recyclerview shows the items with this origin city and doesn't become empty . 
this is my function for filter:

```
public void filter()
{
    String filterOrigin = txtOriginCity.getText().toString();
    String filterDestination = txtDestinationCity.getText().toString();

    for (int i = 0; i < freightsList.size(); i++)
        hold.add(freightsList.get(i));

    freightsList.clear();

    if (filterDestination.equals("allCities") && filterOrigin.equals("allCities"))

        freightsList.addAll(hold);

    else if (filterDestination.equals("allCities") || filterOrigin.equals("allCities"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hold.size(); i++)
        {
            if (hold.get(i).getDestination_city().equals(filterDestination)
                    ||
                    hold.get(i).getOrigin_city().equals(filterOrigin))
            {
                freightsList.add(hold.get(i));
            }
        }
    } else if (!(filterDestination.equals("allCities") && filterOrigin.equals("allCities")))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hold.size(); i++)
        {
            if (hold.get(i).getDestination_city().equals(filterDestination)
                    &&
                    hold.get(i).getOrigin_city().equals(filterOrigin))
            {
                freightsList.add(hold.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you're looking for is this one:

```
public void filter()
{
    String filterOrigin = txtOriginCity.getText().toString();
    String filterDestination = txtDestinationCity.getText().toString();

    for (int i = 0; i < freightsList.size(); i++)
        hold.add(freightsList.get(i));

    freightsList.clear();

    if (filterDestination.equals("allCities") && filterOrigin.equals("allCities"))

        freightsList.addAll(hold);

    else 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hold.size(); i++)
        {
            if (hold.get(i).getDestination_city().equals(filterDestination)
                    ||
                    hold.get(i).getOrigin_city().equals(filterOrigin))
            {
                freightsList.add(hold.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```